# How to insert a column name containing space

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I am inserting a fetched column from spreadsheet that contains the space character. I am getting this error:

> Invalid CFML construct found on line 64 at column 43.
>
> ```
> <cfqueryparam value="#[F Repro
> ```

How can I insert it into the table using **ColdFusion**. Below is my code:

```
<cfloop query="exceldata" startrow="2">
  insert into test_excel([F Pro])
  values(<cfqueryparam value="#[F Repro]#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">)
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Redesign your database so none of the columns have spaces in their names.

Answer (score 2):

If the database column name contains a space then you will need to place it within square brackets. Like this:

```
<cfloop query="exceldata" startrow="2">
  insert into test_excel([F Pro])
  values(<cfqueryparam value="#variables["F Repro"]#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">)
</cfloop>
```

ColdFusion does not allow spaces in variable names either. If you are getting the idea, spaces in names is a bad idea. Anyway, if you are stuck with the space you can try accessing the variable using the variables scope. Like this `variables["F Repro"]`

Comment: i am using it in insert like this .  insert into test([F Pro]). and I've more than 50 columns in my db most of them have space.

Comment: The example you posted does not show that.  That part is correct. The ColdFusion variable name is incorrect - `#[F Repro]#`

Comment: @Miguel-F 's code will work _if_ there is a variable in the variables scope with a key of "F Repo" - and that is very unlikely unless you are quite clever with your set statements. What should that variable be? The problem is not likely with your _column name_ but with your _variable name within the cfqueryparam_ .